# In the Walking Dead, how do the survivors get access to clean water?

Tags: the-walking-dead

This is something I've never seen addressed. Presumably, after the world falls apart, the water network probably didn't last much longer due to damage/leakage/contamination/lack of pumps operating.

<s>Access to water never seems to be a problem for the survivors.</s>

**EDIT**
See accepted answer below, access to water has definitely been a problem addressed by the show on several occasions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### TL;DR:  The survivors get water a number of ways, mostly depending on their location.

**Sources include:**

- **Wells**
- **Ponds, creeks, and quarries**
- **A bottled water delivery truck**
- **A fire truck**
- **Rainwater collected in several different ways**
- **Desalinated seawater (on *Fear the Walking Dead*)**

---

As for your comment:

> Access to water never seems to be a problem for the survivors.

This isn't true.  It was a *major* problem in the first half of season five, and has been mentioned at several other points on the show.

---

---

## *The Walking Dead*:

### Primary Locations:

#### The Quarry:

While the survivors were camping at a quarry on the outskirts of Atlanta, they boiled water from the quarry for drinking and sanitation:

> *Shane drives back to the camp with water*
>
> [image]
>   <sup>*Shane hauling water from the quarry to the camp*</sup>
>
> Shane: **Water's here, y'all. Just a reminder to boil before use.**
>   -  The Walking Dead, Season 1, Episode 3:  *Tell it to the Frogs*

[image]
<sup>*Shane goofing around with Ed at the quarry*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Quarry campsite filming location on Google Maps - note all the water*</sup>

---

#### Herschel's Farm:

As you might expect, Herschel's farm has several wells:

> Glenn:  **Miss, what's the water situation here?**
>
> Maggie:  **Got five wells on our land. House draws directly from number one. Number-two well is right over there. We use it for the cattle but it's just as pure.** Take what you need. There's a cart and containers in the generator shed behind the house.
>   -  *The Walking Dead*, Season 2, Episode 4:  *Cherokee Rose*

Unbeknownst to Maggie, the well she tells Glenn to use is *not* just as pure as the others, as Dale and T-Dog soon discover:

[image]
<sup>*T-Dog pumping water to slake his thirst while Dale snoops around a bit*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*This is the well version of the world's worst Cracker Jacks prize*</sup>

But, as Maggie said, there *are* four other wells that don't have rotting zombies in them, so the group uses those for the duration of their stay on the farm.

---

#### The Prison:

By the premiere of season four, the prison has been adapted to support a fairly large community of survivors.  Water is drawn by a hand-pump from a pond and small creek just outside the fences.  The pond and creek are rather gross and muddy, so the survivors must have boiled their water before drinking it.

[image]
<sup>*Prison exterior, with the pond in the foreground*</sup>

[image]
[image]
<sup>*Carol clears a clog in the intake hose filter*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Carol operating the hand-pump while Rick just stands there watching*</sup>

The prison set was actually the back lot of Raleigh Studios in Senoia, Georgia<sup>1</sup>, and the pond and creek (called "Keg Creek" in real life) can be seen in this satellite photo from Google Maps:

[image]
<sup>*The prison set - the larger pond on the right is the one [where the Governor](http://img2.tvtome.com/i/u/9f2142f08afb4e26ce1692d197848377.jpg) disposed of [Pete's reanimated body](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/walkingdead/images/8/83/Zombie_Pete.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140121055348)*</sup>

---

#### Alexandria:

Before the outbreak, the Alexandria property was designed as a fairly expensive, ecologically friendly gated community.  As such, it was equipped with cisterns for water collection.

> Rick:  What is this place?
>
> Deanna:  This is the start of sustainability. That's what the brochures we found say. **This was a planned community with its own** solar grid, **cisterns**, eco-based sewage filtration. Starting in the low 800,000s... (laughs) .. if there is such a thing.
>   -  *The Walking Dead*, Season 5, Episode 12:  *Remember*

In a few shots, we can see the cisterns.  They are small plastic rain-barrels of the sort you can buy at any big home improvement store, and are filled via a pipe from the gutters on each house:

[image]

---

### Secondary Locations:

#### Rick's hospital room:

When Rick emerges from his coma in the series premiere, the taps are still working:

[image]

---

#### Just before finding Herschel's farm:

The group is so desperate for water that they try to siphon it from cars while stuck on the road:

> I can siphon more fuel from these cars for a start. **Maybe some water.**
>   -  *The Walking Dead*, Season 2, Episode 1, *What Lies Ahead*

And Shane and Glenn are almost euphoric when Shane finds a truck full of massive bottles of water.  The looks on their faces shows just how desperate they had been, and how much this discovery means to them:

> *Shane spots a truck with "Mountain Spring Water" written on the back, and decides to investigate*
>
> [image][image]
>
> *Shane opens the truck, sees all the jugs of water inside, and steps back, awestruck*
>
> [image]
>
> Shane:  **Glenn, were we short on water?**
>
> *Glenn looks over, sees the water, and his jaw drops*
>
> [image]
>
> *Shane pops the cap off a bottle of water and lets it pour into his mouth*
>
> [image]
>
> *Glenn laughs maniacally*
>
> [image]
>
> Glenn:  Save me some!
>
> *Shane lets the water pour over his head*
>
> [image]
>
> Shane:  It's like being baptized, man.
>   -  *The Walking Dead*, Season 2, Episode 1, *What Lies Ahead*

---

#### The Grove:

When Carol, Tyreese, Lizzy, Meeka, and Judith are on their own after the prison was destroyed, they find a house in a grove of pecan trees, and Tyreese fixes the old water pump in the yard:

[image]

Which is a marked improvement over what they *had* been doing for water:

[image]

---

#### On the road after Terminus:

The survivors are near death from dehydration.  Some of them try digging for water in dry creek beds, to no avail.  Then they come across a stash of bottled water in the road with a note reading "from a friend".

[image]
[image]

As desperate as the group is, they are also understandably suspicious, having just escaped a community of cannibals who lured them in with promises of safety, then tried to eat them.  Only Eugene is willing to drink the water;  Abraham, however, slaps the bottle from his hand before he can do so.

[image]
[image]

Just then, their luck changes, and they make good use of a sudden, torrential downpour.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

#### Attorney's office:

In episode six of season five, *Consumed*, we see a flashback to what Carol did after being kicked out of the prison by Rick in season four.  She went to a nearby office.  We see her rigging some plastic bags outside the window to catch rain:

[image]

---

#### On the road to DC:

When Rosita, Eugene, Abraham, Tara, and Glenn are on their ill-fated trip to DC, they first find water in the tank of a firetruck:

[image]
[image]

Later, they find a disgusting shallow creek, and Rosita builds a water filter to remove most of the nastiness:

[image]

> Tara: **So, you just built a water filter in about two minutes, huh?**
>
> Rosita:  Eugene taught me. **Takes a while, but it'll be clear. Then we can boil it.**
>   -  *The Walking Dead*, Season 5, Episode 7: *Crossed*

---

#### Grady Memorial Hospital:

The hospital where Beth is kept captive has at least two [large rain collection bins on the roof](http://www.rainsaucers.com/blog/2015/12/07/walking-dead-rain-barrels):

[image]

---

## *Fear the Walking Dead*:

The protagonists on FTWD have been fortunate, compared to the characters on TWD.  At first, they were  in their homes with running water;  then the water stopped flowing, but the military supplied them with bottled water.  In season two, they've spent most of their time on a yacht with a desalinization system that makes sea water safe to drink:

> Man on radio:  Yeah, how about you? You have water?
>
> Alicia:  **Uh, yeah, we have a desalinization system.**
>   -  *Fear the Walking Dead*, season two, episode one, *Monster*

---

---

*Notes:*

<sup>1</sup>*As you can see on [my Google Map of TWD filming locations](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WvmfvHBsCGuq6GT63fLA7F3iU8Q&usp=sharing),  Senoia is the most frequent filming location for* The Walking Dead:

[image]
<sup>*TWD filming locations in Senoia, Georgia*</sup>

Comment: I stand majorly corrected... Great answer sir.

Answer (score 4):

They have easy access to fire. One could argue they simply boil water and place it in containers. As RBC stated below, they could also  [collect rainwater](http://chemistry.about.com/od/waterchemistry/fl/Can-You-Drink-Rain-Water.htm), but to ensure its safety you should still boil it.

Comment: They could also collect rainwater, which will be safe to drink. Water from rivers/lakes will be good enough for washing/bathing.

Comment: A fair answer, rainwater is fine but I've never seen them collecting on the show, nor seen it raining much. Boiling water is also fine but with lowland rivers and/or potentially contaminated lakes etc, you may want some further filtration. I think I'm just surprised no one has got sick from the water. This is where TWD lacks-details of everyday life.